# os.path.join producing an extra forward slash

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

I am trying to join an absolute path and variable folder path depending on the variable `run`. However when I use the following code it inserts a forward slash after a string, which I don't require. How can I remove the slash after `Folder_`?

```
import os
currentwd = os.getcwd()
folder = '001'
run_folder = os.path.join(currentwd, 'Folder_', folder)
print run_folder
```

The output I get using this code is:

```
/home/xkr/Workspace/Folder_/001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking `os.path.join()` to take multiple path elements and join them. *It is doing its job*.

Don't use `os.path.join()` to produce filenames; just use concatenation:

```
run_folder = os.path.join(currentwd, 'Folder_' + folder)
```

or use string formatting; the latter can give you such nice features such as automatic padding of integers:

```
folder = 1
run_folder = os.path.join(currentwd, 'Folder_{:03d}'.format(folder))
```

That way you can increment `folder` past 10 or 100 and still have the correct number of leading zeros.

Note that you don't have to use `os.getcwd()`; you could also use `os.path.abspath()`, it'll make relative paths absolute based on the current working directory:

```
run_folder = os.path.abspath('Folder_' + folder)
```